# Insert element at index 0, NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am having trouble inserting an element at the first index to `CoreData`

```
let appDelegate =
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Thing",
  inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

let thing = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
  insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

thing.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
thing.setValue(category, forKey: "category")

do {
  try managedContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
}
```

How do I insert `thing` at index 0? Is it possible or do I have to rewrite all the data? Thanks!

Comment: why did you save context before inserting, save must be done after?
`things` is an 
    @NSManaged NSOrderedSet ?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: there is no more "insert" in your code, question is now invalid
You just add object into the core data context as a "floating" object
You must have a `Things` object with an ordered set of `Thing` to talk about inserting at first position

Comment: im asking about this, do i have to clear core data then write again with ordered array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot *insert* a new `NSManagedObject` at a particular index.  The order things are held in the store is for CoreData and SQLite to manage.  You should instead ensure that you *fetch* the objects in the order that you want.  This is done by specifying a **sort descriptor** ([NSSortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/)) for your fetch request.  So if you want things ordered by `name`, you would use:

```
let nameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key:"name", ascending:true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [nameSort]
```

If you want some other sort order, if necessary add an attribute to your Entity to represent that sort order, and set the appropriate values for each object you create.